# Redirect old Wordpress Posts to new URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am assuming I have to use .htaccess, but what do i do to tell my oldsite http://oldsite.com/post-slug to redirect any "post-slug" to http://newsite.com/post-slug automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your old page add the following to the .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://newsite.com/$1 [QSA,NC,R=301]
```

That will redirect each link including the page name to the new domain. The flags will also sent the additional parameters and make the URL case-insensitive. The R=301 will tell search engines, that it is a permanent redirect so they might update theit indexes faster.